# Can't resize the form by dragging its borders

Tags: c#, winforms

**Form's AutoSize**: *False*.
**Form's AutoSizeMode**:  *Grow and Shrink*.

Issue: I cant resize my form by dragging its borders, I can only do that by dragging that grip thing on the bottom right side of the form.

Is there any other property on the form that I sohlud change to fix this problem?

Here is also a screen shot of the hierarchy of controls on the form...maybe setting on lower level controls on the form is causing this?

[image]

Comment: Have you set any minimum/maximum size for your form?

Comment: no, haven't set min-max limitations on anytihng :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure the FormBorderStyle is set to Sizable, and that the SizeGripStyle property is set to Auto or Hide.

Comment: yep, that's on Sizeable...GripStyle was on Show, Now I am gonna change it to Hide and see what happens.

Comment: Do you have a StatusStrip on the form? A StatusStrip with the SizingGrip  property set to True may affect the ability of the window to be resized in other ways.

Comment: So at this point, you have a window with a Sizable border and no sizing grips displayed anywhere on it, but it still won't let you resize the window except at the bottom right?

Comment: Yes, FormBorderStyle is set to Sizeable as you mentioned..but still can't drag its border to resize it :( and well I also set that GripStyle to hide, so that is gone too...

Comment: I'd set the AutoSizeMode property to its default GrowOnly, and also make sure the MaximumSize and MinimumSize are set to sane values. The sizing grip may have somehow allowed you to bypass these sizes.

Comment: yeah, I played with a bunch of stuff...GrowOnly one of them... also set the table layout to be Dock to Top, removed the Grip, .. these all together worked...thanks Sir.

Comment: @KeithS - thx. Setting the form's AutoSizeMode to "GrowOnly" was the specific thing that resolved the problem for me - couldn't resize by the edges of the window.  My situation was in an inherited form where as long as (by trying all combos of the setting in base & subclassed form) GrowOnly in the subclassed form was set, it worked.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problems. Setting the form's AutoSizeMode to GrowOnly helps, but then I cannot make the window smaller; it keeps on growing. Did you solve this particular problem, and, if so, how?

Comment: people keep mentioning stuff that has nothing to do with resizability. the SizeGripStyle has NOTHING to do with being able to resize the window.  You can Hide it on all your dialogs and still allow resizing...

Comment: The solution for me was to set the form property AutoSizeMode to GrowOnly. .Net 4.7.2 WinForm project on Visual Studio 2019 and Win 10 1909

Answer (score 40):

Because this is not in the answers, I'll write this here.

The problem seems to be caused by the form's AutoSizeMode being on GrowAndShrink, and not GrowOnly, which is the default setting. Resetting to GrowOnly fixed the issue.

(confirmed on MSVS2013 with .net 4.5 on Win7)

Comment: Correct. I'm approving.

Comment: @Cordell mentioned the answer doesn't make sense, and the last sentence should read "Resetting to **GrowOnly** fixed the issue." I can't reproduce the fix since I've moved to Win8.1 MSVS2016.

Comment: As suggested above, after setting AutoSizeMode=GrowOnly
I was able to resize window from any side : left, right, top, bottom

It is really confusing word. I don't know why it is called GrowOnly when this option give power to either make small or big

Comment: Tinkered around for a hour and this finally fixed it. I can resize my Form again. Before that I was able to resize it once by dragging the ToolStripBar and after that nothing happened anymore. Very strange. Anyway my Panel resizes in the designer as desired but on runtime it holds the initial size. Any suggestion?

Comment: I edited to say "Resetting to GrowOnly".  I hit the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem if maximum size was set. Please set it to `0` or to bigger than now. After that you can move the border wherever you want. Change  `FormBorderStyle` or  `SizeGripStyle` can't help if maximum size is too small to new settings.

Answer (score 4):

Tried everything in the above (and Microsoft's forums) couldn't get it to resize.  Finally just opened another instance with a form I hadn't dorked up and compared.  Here's what needed set.  All are mentioned above but not as a combination.

In the form's property window (or in the code).

Autosize:  False = allows resizing both dimensions (True = only width adjusted).

AutosizeMode:  GrowOnly = allows both growing and shrinking.

FormBorderStyle:  Sizeable.

Comment: It's FormBorderStyle: Sizable now.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.formborderstyle?view=netcore-3.1#examples

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, I can not manually change the size of form or controls in manual mode.  Tried all the above, checked prior forms in the project, I could resize them.

Then, closed VS 2010, reopened the project, and I can resize the form and controls ....

" Did you try the  power switch ...  ;)"

Comment: Unbelievable, I had the same problem in VS2022 and this worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
int height = 960;
int width = 1280;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(width, height);
```

this way you can get a fixed form size...otherwise visual studio automatically changes it

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was causing this for me. This had been a problem for years! None of the things listed here helped, and indeed, all of them were already set as suggested.

It turned out that I couldn't make a window smaller in width if **any** control was anchored to the right edge, or smaller in height if **any** control was anchored to the bottom edge.